Access different variables using macro
Suppose I have 4 variables:
float f0 = 0.1;
float f1 = 1.2;
float f2 = 2.3;
float f3 = 3.4;

Is there a way I can write a macro to access these variables without eventually writing them? Basically I need something like this:
float sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) sum += MACRO(i);
cout<<sum<<endl;

//OUTPUT: 7.0


Just use an array. Also avoid using macros.

I'm in a GPU context where I don't have easy access to arrays usage. In my case, having a macro would be handy.

You should mention that in your question.

Something along the lines of #define MACRO(i) (i==0 ? f0 : i == 1 ? f1 : i == 2 ? f2 : f3)

There is no portable way to do this.  Arrays are the solution here.  Arrays should be using a GPU ocding

I suppose you could have all the floats in a tuple as well.  That would be easy to get this kind of behavior.

@IgorTandetnik good catch! Feel free to post it as answer. It is not very scalable but I'll have no more than 5 variables so it fits.

What GPU context? This sounds like a misguided XY problem. Your question is also entirely unclear without explaining why arrays are not the solution.

We do note that the macro version uses more code than the "hand coded" version. Just don't get too cute when trying to "save" coding.

PP macros don't work on dynamic values. That means they can't be executed at runtime...
